# How To Properly Switch from Absolute Positioning to Fixed

Tags: css, css-position

I am having a problem where I position a dialog with "position:absolute" and it works fine putting it in the center of the screen. But then I switch "position:absolute" with "position:fixed" after that and it causes the position to not be in the center. (I'm using latest stable Google Chrome I have.)

What's the trick so that when I make this switch, it will always be in the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use these styles to make it appear dead-center:

```
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:400px;  /* adjust as per your needs */
height:400px;   /* adjust as per your needs */
margin-left:-200px;   /* half of width above */
margin-top:-200px;   /* half of height above */
```

So `position` should be specified. The `top` and `left` should be `50%`. The `margin-left` and `margin-top` should be negative one half of the width and height of the box respectively.

*Notice that `position:fixed` does not work in IE6.*